# javascript loop isn't re-iterating on 2nd counter

Tags: javascript, loops

I have just fiddled around with javascript, I'm just trying to compare 2 arrays and remove all the english vowels from the string to later return it with no vowels.

The iteration for `j` representing the array of vowels (`arr`) stops at length but I want it to re-loop on every iteration for `i`.

Here is my basic code:

```js
let sentence = 'eitan was here';

function disemvowel(str) {
  let arr = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  let letters = str.split('');
  let i, j;
  for (i = 0, j = 0; i < letters.length && j < arr.length;) {
    console.log('counter: i = ' + i + ', j = ' + j + ', ' + letters[i] + ' vs ' + arr[j] + 'and letters: ' + letters);
    if (letters[i] == arr[j]) {
      if (letters[i] == ' ') {
        i++;
      }
      console.log('IF stopped here: ' + letters[i] + ' at i: ' + i + ', ' + arr[j] + ' at j: ' + j);
      letters.splice(i, 1);
      //console.log('letters after splice: '+ letters);
      i++;
    } else {
      console.log('ELSE stopped here: ' + letters[i] + ' at i: ' + i + ', ' + arr[j] + ' at j: ' + j);
      j++;
    }
  }
  return letters;

}
console.log('letters are: ', disemvowel(sentence));
```

I'm interested to avoid creating loops within loops or separate functions to run `j` for runtime and brevity.

Comment: "_I'm interested to avoid creating loops within loops_" Why, they are a powerful tool.

Comment: @Teemu ,  true but I have this tingling feeling that it wouldn't be necessary here, am I right?

Comment: "_I'm interested to avoid creating loops within loops or seperate functions to run j for runtime_" . Iterating j over a loop of 5 vowels does not going to affect your runtime performance in any way, time complexity will still remain linear.

Comment: But real world apps would use a huge array, why make shortcuts if it could be done in one linear run?

Comment: Check my answer. This is what you exactly needed.

Comment: I wrote back there, but still need the loop ace, thanks.

Comment: Basicly, if you're going to check an array against a string, you have to always create a loop. Whether it would be internal or external is up to you.

Comment: @clusterBuddy It does not matter if you do it in single run or in loop within loop your runtime will be linear, since one loop (vowel one) will always have a constant runtime. Micro optimisations are unnecessary here, you would not gain any significant performance improvement.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia -that is part true, yet you need to consider the fact that the array would be a huge state object, this is just a mock, at that point the more elements you have bringing in a second loop means twice the for that state comparing itself to another state, state was an example -no need for `Object.assign()` in this question, and thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sentence = 'eitan was here';
function disemvowel(str){
arr = ['a','e','i','o','u'];

arr.forEach((itm)=>{
    var re = new RegExp(itm,'g');
    str = str.replace(re,'');
})
return str;
}
console.log(disemvowel(sentence));
```

Comment: thanks , hope it solves your problem of using one loop

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to loop over to remove the vowels from the string. The best way to achieve this is to use character class in `replace()` like this

```
let sentence = 'eitan was here';
sentence  = sentence .replace(/[aeiou]/g,'');
```

You can also use the OR operator (|) like this

```
sentence = sentence.replace(/a|e|i|o|u/g,'');
```

Comment: awesome answer but I need to stick to the for loop.

Comment: Could you please mark it and up vote it so that others can know it is a proper answer.

Comment: I voted it up because it's a nice answer but it doesn't solve the 1 loop issue, I would want `j` to re-loop on every `i` iteration.

Comment: Ok let me look over to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset j to 0. Also, You can not splice the same array that you are looping through i.e letters array in this case.

```
<script>
 let sentence = 'eitan was here';
 function disemvowel(str) {
  let arr = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  let letters = str.split('');
  let output = [];
  let i,j;
 for (i=0,j=0; i<letters.length && j<arr.length;){
    if(letters[i] == arr[j]){
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }else{
        j++;
        if(j >= arr.length){
            output.push(letters[i]);
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }
     }
   }
  return output;
 }
 console.log('letters are: ', disemvowel(sentence));
</script>
```